# Visual Studio compiling with JNI causes errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, java-native-interface

whenever I try to compile my C++ project that has `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\include` included and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\include\win32` included I get multiple [errors from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76A3G.png). Specifically from jvmticmlr.h. No changes have been made to jvmticmlr.h either.

Comment: Don't post error messages or code as images. Put them in your question as text instead.

Comment: IIRC, you have to include Windows.h before jni.h